# Loop through an array column in order to find the required values python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a minimum and a maximum value, i also have a 70X3 array. I would like to find all the values from the second column of the array which are within the range of the min and max value and export all 3 columns of the array for those values.

For example

```
A=[2,3,4
   3,5,6
   5,5,5
   5,6,7
   10,11,22
   3,50,6]
```

Max value is 11 and min is 5 the result of the matrix would be something like

```
B=[3,5,6
   5,5,5
   5,6,7
   10,11,22]
```

Up till now i what i did is :

```
for i in MatrixA[:,1]):
    if i<maximum and i>minimum:
        aa.append(i)
aa=np.asarray(aa)
```

But this only finds the range of values i need from the second column and not the corresponding values from column 1 and 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
A[numpy.logical_and(5 <= A[:, 1], A[:, 1] <= 11), :]
```

Answer (score 2):

With simple ***numpy*** expression:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[2,3,4],[3,5,6], [5,5,5], [5,6,7],[10,11,22], [3,50,6]])
b = a[(a[:,1] >= 5) & (a[:,1] <= 11)]

print(b)
```

The output:

```
[[ 3  5  6]
 [ 5  5  5]
 [ 5  6  7]
 [10 11 22]]
```

---

- `a[:,1]` - considering values from specified axis (`1` axis, 2nd column)